# How can i use .load function to insert content into different Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am kind of a newbie to jQuery so sincere apologies if my question seems very superficial. I wanted to know how i can use buttons in one `div` to place content in another `div` when any one of the buttons is clicked on using jQuery. Each button of course will be loading its own content in the specific `div` that i want changed.

Thank you in anticipation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty simple:

```
$("#buttonA").on("click", function() {
    $("#theDiv").load("http://theUrl");
});

$("#buttonB").on("click", function() {
    $("#theDiv").load("http://theOtherUrl");
});
```

Replace `#buttonA`, `#buttonB`, `#theDiv` with your specific selectors.

A better way would be to use `data` attributes:

```
<button class="link-btn" data-url="http://theUrl">load A</button>
<button class="link-btn" data-url="http://theOtherUrl">load B</button>
```

And...

```
$(".link-btn").on("click", function() {
    $("#theDiv").load($(this).data("url"));
});
```

Comment: i am having trouble again, is there anything wrong with the following? $(document).ready(function(){

$("#bt1").on("click", function() {
    $('#content').load('html_docs/other.html .text');
});

}); When i click on the button the Div that is suppose to be filled just stays blank, the height of the #content div is set to auto

Comment: @Sich I see nothing wrong here at first glance. Take a look at the console output to see if there are any errors (like a wrong url for instance) and inspect the ajax call return. If you find nothing here, post a different question with all the details you can gather.

Comment: The console does not show any errors at all, i know what ajax is but embarrassingly i don't exactly know how to "inspect the ajax call return" like i said am a newbie but looking to say bye to that status soon. Thank you very much for your help and time. Let me just post my whole site plus the code am trying to use

Comment: No worries, don't post everything, extract just the code that is failing and post it as a new question if needed. To inspect the AJAX call return, the most straightforward way IMO is to use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (a Firefox addon), as it displays the ajax calls nicely in its console.

Answer (score 0):

Following jquery can help

```
$('#buttonid').click(function(){
$('#div2id').load('page.html');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
$('#yourDivId').load('content.html');   // Your content source
```